# How to convert string to integer with parseInt?

Tags: java, string, integer

I have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Valtozas> lista = new ArrayList<Valtozas>();

        try {
            File fajl = new File("c://data//uzemanyag.txt");
            Scanner szkenner = new Scanner(fajl, "UTF8");

            while (szkenner.hasNext()) {
                String sor = szkenner.nextLine();
                String [] darabok = sor.split(";");
                String szoveg = darabok[0];
                Valtozas valtozas = new Valtozas(Integer.valueOf(darabok[0]), Integer.valueOf(darabok[1]), Integer.valueOf(darabok[2]));
                lista.add(valtozas);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }


        //3.FELADAT
        System.out.println("3.Feladat: Változások száma: "+lista.size());
    }

}
```

Here I want to convert the String to int, but I cant. I tried the Integer.Valueof(darabok[0]), but its not working. And nothing is happening, so the code is build, but quit from the while.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(darabok[0]);` and **see** what value **isn't** an `int`.

Comment: try to log an error in catch block to see if really nothing is happening

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` expects a string with only numeric characters. So, if you pass anything other than the permutation of the characters "0123456789.E-", you will get an exception.

Comment: Post some lines of the file you're trying to access. It might help us to figure out the problem

Comment: Don't mute your try/catch. Allow the **catch** to let you know what's wrong.

Comment: Put `e.printStackTrace();` inside the `catch` block. Then any exceptions in the program will be shown in console.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source code you have shown us, the problem is that there is a format mismatch between the input file and the program you are trying to read.

The program reads the file a line at a time, and splits it into fields using a single semicolon (with no whitespace!) as the file separator.  Then it tries to parse the first three fields of each split line as integers.

For this to work the following must be true:

- Every line must have at least three fields.  (Otherwise you will get a `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` exception.)
- The three fields must match the following regex: `-?[0-9]+` i.e. an optional minus signed followed by one or more decimal digits.
- The resulting number must be between `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Elaborating on the above:

- Leading and trailing whitespace characters are not allowed.
- Embedded decimals markers and grouping characters are not allowed.
- Scientific notation is not allowed.
- Numbers that are too large or too small are not allowed.

Note that if any of the above constraints is not met, then the runtime system will throw an exception.  Unfortunately, you surround your code with this:

```
    try {
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

That basically ignores all exceptions by catching them and doing nothing in the handler block.  You are saying to Java "if anything goes wrong, don't tell me about it!".  So, naturally, Java doesn't tell you what is going wrong.

**DON'T EVER DO THIS**.  This is called exception squashing, and it is a really bad idea<sup>1</sup>.

There are two ways to address this:

1. Print or log the stacktrace; e.g.

   ```
     catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
   ```
2. Remove the try / catch, and add `throws IOException` to the signature of your `main` method.

(You can't *just* remove the try / catch because `new Scanner(fajl, "UTF8")` throws `IOException`.  That's a checked exception so must be handled or declared in the method signature.)

Once you have dealt with the exception properly you will get an exception message and stacktrace that tells you what is actually going wrong.  Read it, understand it, and fix your program.

---

<sup>1 - It is like taping over the "annoying" red light that indicates that your car's oil level is low!</sup>

Comment: This is my line, that I try to read:
2011.01.12;363;354
2011.01.19;366;359
2011.01.26;363;359
2011.02.02;359;357
2011.02.16;360;360
2011.02.23;365;362 etc.
So my lines are numbers, but to read it, I have to convert to String. But after that I want to use as int.
My exception: 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2011.01.12"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
 at Uzemanyag.main(Uzemanyag.java:21)

Comment: Now I only convert the second and third row, and its work. So I cant convert the date from String to int.

Comment: "*So my lines are numbers*" -  I disagree with that, and so does Java.  And most importantly, Java is correct.  They are NOT integers according to the definition that Java uses, and that I have given to you.  *"So I cant convert the date from String to int."*  - You can't do it by using `Integer.parseInt`. Because a date is a date ...  not an integer!

Comment: The way to convert a date to an integer is to construct and use a `DateTimeFormatter` .  There are examples in the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: The reason that I want to convert the date to Integer, because after I have to work whit that. For example I have to decide, that the date's year is even or not. 
Im don't know this Date format, so I need some help to understand it. Can I use the Date format, to split the year or the day so I can decide that it is even or not. 
My way to make this solution was that I have this String (the date, like "2012.12.01") And a want this String spit (String row = v.getDatum(); String [] date = row.split(".");). But the date array is empty, so the splitting is not working.

Comment: Don't use split to parse dates.  Use a formatter as I said in my previous comment. If you don't know anything about using date / time values in Java, I suggest that you start by reading the tutorial.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html  (Or search for other StackOverflow questions).

Comment: FWIW - the reason split(".") is failing is that it takes a *regex* string as a parameter, not a simple string.  This is explained in the javadoc.  But don't do it that way!   And hint: start *reading* the javadocs.  If you don't read them you will never really understand how Java works.